# Where are Telemetry files generated in Firefox for Android (Fennec)

Tags: android, firefox, fennec, telemetry

In Firefox for Android (Fennec), after each iteration i.e. opening a website from Fennec, it will auto-generate a telemetry file in your profile `saved-telemetry-pings` directory.

This generated file is using a random filename.

So I want to know where in the Fennec code this file is generated? 
I need to know to code path leading to this file generation.

Any help or code pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[`/mobile/android/base/ANRReporter.java`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/base/ANRReporter.java) on Android and
[`/toolkit/components/telemetry/TelemetryFile.jsm`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/telemetry/TelemetryFile.jsm) on Desktop, apparently.

Just search [MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org/), e.g. for [all files with `Telemetry` in their path](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/find?string=Telemetry&tree=mozilla-central&hint=) or [files containing the `saved-telemetry-pings` string](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=saved-telemetry-pings), (or get the sources and `grep`/`ag`/`whatever` over them).

There is likely a multitude of ways this code may eventually be reached, so you'll need to check what code paths you're particularly interested in yourself.